# How do you ensure a service worker caches a consistent set of files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have a progressive web app (PWA) consisting of several files including `index.html`, `manifest.json`, `bundle.js` and `serviceWorker.js`. I update my app by uploading all these files to my host. In case it matters, I am using Firebase so I use `firebase deploy` to upload the files.

Usually everything works correctly: When an existing user opens the app they still see the old version but in the background the new service worker `install`s any changed files to the cache. Then when the user next opens the app it `activate`s and they see the new version.

But I have a problem when a user opens the app a short time after I deploy it. What seems to happen is: **The host delivers the new `serviceWorker.js` but the old `bundle.js`**. And so the `install` puts old `bundle.js` in its new cache. The user gets the old functionality or worse might get an app made up of an inconsistent mixture of new and old files.

I guess it could be argued that it is the host's fault for not updating atomically, but I have no control over Firebase. And it does not sound possible anyway because the browser is sending a series of independent fetches and there can be no guarantee that they will all return a consistent version.

In case it helps, here is my `serviceWorker.js`. The `cacheName` strings such as `"app1-a0f43550e414"` are generated by my build pipeline. Here `a0f43550e414` is the hash of the latest `bundle.js` so that the cache is only updated if the content of `bundle.js` has changed.

```
"use strict";
const appName = "app1";
const cacheLookup = {
    "app1-aefa820f62d2": "/",
    "app1-a0f43550e414": "bundle.js",
    "app1-23d94a4a7388": "manifest.json"
};
self.addEventListener("install", function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        Promise.all(Object.keys(cacheLookup).map(cacheName =>
            caches.open(cacheName)
                .then(cache => cache.add(cacheLookup[cacheName]))
        ))
    );
});
self.addEventListener("activate", event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(cacheNames =>
            Promise.all(cacheNames.map(cacheName => {
                if (cacheLookup[cacheName]) {
                    // cacheName holds a file still needed by this version
                } else if (!cacheName.startsWith(appName + "-")) {
                    // Do not delete the cache of other apps at same scope
                } else {
                    console.log("Deleting out of date cache:", cacheName);
                    return caches.delete(cacheName);
                }
            }))
        )
    );
});
const handleCacheMiss = request =>
    new Promise((_, reject) => {
        reject(Error("Not in service worker cacheLookup: " + request.url));
    });
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
    const request = event.request;
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(request).then(cachedResponse =>
            cachedResponse || handleCacheMiss(request)
        )
    );
});
```

I have considered bundling all my HTML, CSS and JavaScript into a giant file so it cannot be inconsistent. But a PWA need several supporting files that cannot be bundled including the service worker, manifest and icons. If I bundle all that I can, the user can still get stuck with an old version of the bundle and still have inconsistent supporting files. And anyway, in the future I would like to increase granularity by doing less bundling and having more files so on a typical update only a few small files would need to be fetched.

I have also considered uploading `bundle.js` and the other files with a different filename for each version. The service worker's `fetch` could hide the name change so other files like `index.html` can still refer to it as `bundle.js`. But I don't see how this works the first time a browser loads the app. And I don't think you can rename `index.html` or `manifest.json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your request for `bundle.js` inside of your `install` handler might be fulfilled by the HTTP cache, instead of via the network.

You can try changing this current snippet:

```js
cache.add(cacheLookup[cacheName])
```

to explicitly create a `Request` object that has its [cache mode](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-cache-mode) set to `reload` to ensure that the response isn't provided by the HTTP cache:

```js
cache.add(new Request(cacheLookup[cacheName], {cache: 'reload'})
```

Alternatively, if you're concerned about non-atomic global deployments and you can go through the effort to generate `sha256` or better hashes as part of your build process, you can make use of [subresource integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) to ensure that you're getting the correct response bytes from the network that your new service worker expects.

Adapting your code would something like the following, where you'd actually have to generate the correct `sha256` hashes for each file you care about during build time:

```
const cacheLookup = {
    "sha256-[hash]": "/",
    "sha256-[hash]": "bundle.js",
    "sha256-[hash]": "manifest.json"
};

// Later...
cache.add(new Request(cacheLookup[cacheName], {
  cache: 'reload',
  integrity: cacheName,
}));
```

If there's an SRI mismatch, then the request for a given resource will fail, and that will cause the `cache.add()` to reject, which will in turn cause the overall service worker installation to fail. Service worker installation will be retried the next time an [update check](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#updates) happens, at which point (hopefully!) the deployment will be finished and the SRI will be valid.

Comment: Thank you, I will certainly add this to my service worker. It probably explains and fixes the instance of the problem I saw. But I still worry that while multiple files are being uploaded to a server there is still a small time window where the files are inconsistent and the possibility that a service worker's install may cache an invalid set of files. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: The solution to that, if you can't orchestrate your deployments to be atomic globally, is [subresource integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity). I can update the example to illustrate how to use it.